# Loop over all files except ones containing "error"

Tags: bash

I want to select all files with log extension and to not contain "error" word in their name.
I've try this but doesn't work

```
for i in *.log | grep -vs "error"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`extglob` option](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob?highlight=%28extglob%29#extglob) for that

```
shopt -s extglob; for f in !(*error*).log; do echo "$f"; done; shopt -u extglob;
```

### `extglob`

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the 
>   following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using 
>   one  or  more  of  the following sub-patterns:
>
> - **?(pattern-list)**
>        Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
> - ***(pattern-list)**
>        Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - **+(pattern-list)**
>        Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - **@(pattern-list)**
>        Matches one of the given patterns
> - **!(pattern-list)**
>        Matches anything except one of the given patterns

### Tests

#### With `extglob`

```
shopt -s extglob; for f in !(*error*).log; do echo "$f"; done; shopt -u extglob;
```

> alternatives.log auth.log dpkg.log …

#### Without `extglob`

```
for f in *.log; do echo "$f"; done
```

> alternatives.log auth.log **boot.log** **bootstrap.log** dpkg.log …

Comment: Also consider `printf '%s\n' !(*error*).log`. And using `nullglob` could also be better.

Comment: I prefer the use of `for` loop as it's really fast to expand to something more complex that just printing filename. +1 for the `nullglob`

Comment: The test output is inconsistent, seemingly replacing "error" with "boot".

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping anyway, exit the loop early for the ones you don't want.

```
for i in *.log; do
    case $i in *error* ) continue ;; esac
    :  loop
done
```

Unlike the `extglob` solution, this is completely portable even to ancient Bourne shell.

Comment: nice thinking about portability. Don't you need quotes on the `case $i`?

Comment: Good question, but no -- `case` is different.

Comment: does it behave in the same way as `[[ ]]`? If so is this behavior also available in old shells?

Comment: I'm certain that it's POSIX but can't really comment on whether legacy shells had exactly the same behavior. I sort of expect they would, or else POSIX would have mandated quoting simply for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I probably answered it wrong. Using `extglob` is a better solution. But this is another way:

```
printf '%s\n' *.log | grep -v error
```

---

Previous answer:

No need to use a `for` loop. You can just pass all files at once:

```
grep -vsl error -- *.log
```

And `--` is an optional option-file-argument separator to prevent `grep` from misinterpreting a filename starting with `-` as a bad option.

Depending on implementation, `-F` or `fgrep` may also make it faster:

```
grep -Fvsl error -- *.log
```

Comment: Not often do we see the `--` :). But why `grep` entire files where we are just interesting in there name? This will slow things down and your `-F` suggestion is an attempt to fast things up

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez Yes the previous answer was a mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the script below command `file` given for example, you can change it to any command you need. The script fits also for files which have spaces in their names.

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

for f in *.log 
do 
if [ -n "$(echo $f  | grep -v error)" ] ; then file $f ;
 fi
done 

IFS="$OIFS"
```